# Laravel 5.7 - Query builder not escaping quotes or backslashes correctly when using updateOrInsert()

Tags: laravel-5, insert-update, addslashes

I have an array with some strings and special caracter in the values.

If I use the insert method it works good.

```
$result = DB::connection('host1')->table('tblName')->insert($data);
```

If I use the update method it works good.

```
$result = DB::connection('host1')->table('tblName')->where('id',$data['id'])->update($data);
```

But if I use the method updateOrInsert it doesn't work. It seems to be an [old issue](https://laravel.io/forum/07-07-2016-query-builder-not-escaping-quotes-or-backslashes-correctly).

```
$result = DB::connection('host1')->table('tblName')->updateOrInsert([
            'id'=>$data['id'],
            $data
        ]);
```

This is the error I get:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'No Annual Fee `1` = ?)) as `exists`' at line 1 (SQL: select exists(select * from `tblName` where (`id` = 56429444 No Annual Fee `1` = 56429444)) as `exists`)
```

It seems to be something that I could solve escaping with `addslashes()` when using SQL EXISTS.. Maybe the first query for this method.

But even If I loop trough the array and escape each value it still not working.

```
foreach ($data as $k=>$v){
   $dt[$k]=addslashes($v);
}
```

Any ide in how to solve it using `updateOrInsert`?

Comment: can you show what the contents are from your $data variable?

Comment: there are manyy keys.. some like `It's simple: $1` or `,"RawLogoImageUrl":"\/\/cdn.nex`  many diferent strings, some escaped json

Comment: just updated the error. Something with SQL EXISTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function signature is:

```
updateOrInsert(array $attributes, array $values = [])
```

So you should keep separated the `$attributes` array that is checked for existence from the `$values` array, something like that:

```
$result = DB::connection('host1')->table('tblName')
          ->updateOrInsert(['id'=>$data['id']], $data);
```